# on flat morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, flatness, schemes

Let $j:U\rightarrow X$ an open immersion between k-schemes of finite type and $f:X\rightarrow S$ a surjective k-morphism of finite type.

We suppose that $f\circ j:U\rightarrow S$ is faithfully flat, does it imply that f is faithfully flat?

Comment: Why the heck should it imply that $f$ is flat? Did you forget a hypothesis?

Comment: There is no reason for $f$ to be flat outside $U$. For example $S=\mathbb{A}^1=U$, $X = \mathbb{A}^1 \sqcup pt$.

Comment: ...or let $f:X\to S$ be any birational morphism and $U\subseteq X$ the locus where it is an isomorphism.

Comment: Is it true when $U$ is "large" in some sense?

Answer (score 2):

In comments to the question, Martin Brandenburg asks if the answer should be positive for $U$ large. Here is one positive result in this direction.

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. A surjective birational $k$-morphism from a connected normal $k$-scheme of finite type to a regular $k$-scheme of finite type that is flat outside of a set of codimension $\geq 2$ is faithfully flat. To see this, use [a purity theorem](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0EA4) and the fact that for a birational morphism with a normal target, the flat locus coincides with the etale locus.

This [fails](https://mathoverflow.net/a/327262/137767) if we drop the assumption on the source or on the target. This also [fails](https://mathoverflow.net/a/328141/137767) if you do not assume that the morphism is birational.